# Springboot and Liberty Server - Spring JPA - Having database credentials in server settings file instead of Spring application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, database-connection, open-liberty

I am using Springboot with Spring JPA.  My application is connecting to database and I am currently using

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@.....
spring.datasource.username=blahblah
spring.datasource.password=xyz
```

, specified in Spring application.properties file.

This is all working fine; however, we dont want to proivide this information to developers but instead let our servers team set these inside the production servers running WAS Liberty (or Open Liberty).

How to use these credentials in Liberty server.xml and have Spring JPA still do what it needs to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring boot documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.M1/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html) indicates that you can use the `spring.datasource.jndi-name` property instead to point at the JNDI name of a configured data source.

Here is how to configure an Oracle data source in Liberty server configuration (server.xml file),

```
<server>
  <featureManager>
    <feature>jdbc-4.2</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <!-- ... other features here -->
  </featureManager>

  <dataSource jndiName="jdbc/oracle">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="OracleJDBCLib"/>
    <properties.oracle URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//..." user="blahblah" password="xyz"/>
  </dataSource>

  <library id="OracleJDBCLib">
    <fileset dir="/path/to/oracle/ojdbc8.jar"/>
  </library>

</server>
```

and then you should be able to set,

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/oracle
```

Here is a [link](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/base?topic=liberty-configuring-relational-database-connectivity-in) to documentation on creating data sources in Liberty.

Comment: Much appreciated @njr.  Exactly what I needed.